# How to call the function every time I click the button?

Tags: javascript

How do I randomize a new number every time I click the button? It works once, but when I click again it's the same numbers. How do I solve this?

HTML:

```
 <div id="center">
    <h1>Dragon</h1>

    <div id="dragonRedHpBar">
        <div id="dragonGreenHpBar"></div>
    </div>

 <span id="hpLeft1"></span>

 <p>The Dragon hit you for: <span id="DragonHit"></span></p>

 <p>You hit a: <span id="MyHit"></span></p>

 <h1>Player</h1>

    <div id="myRedHpBar">
        <div id="myGreenHpBar"></div>
    </div>

    <span id="hpLeft2"></span><br />

    <button id="button" onclick="play()">Fight!</button>

  </div> <!-- End of div #center-->
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() { 
   document.getElementById("hpLeft1").innerHTML= "<b>200/200</b>";
   document.getElementById("hpLeft2").innerHTML = "<b>200/200</b>";
};

var myHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
var dragonHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
var playerHitpoints, dragonHitpoints = 200;
var slaying = true;
```

Here is the function I want to call:

```
function play() { 


    document.getElementById("DragonHit").innerHTML = dragonHit;
    document.getElementById("MyHit").innerHTML = myHit;
}
```

Comment: `<input type="submit" onclick="play()">`

Comment: `<input type="submit">` won't call the function unless it has `action="JavaScript:play();"`
use `<input type="button" onclick="play();">` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the random functions again in your play() function. Currently you've set it so it only runs once when your myHit and dragonHit variables were declared.

```
function play() { 
    myHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
    dragonHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);

    document.getElementById("DragonHit").innerHTML = dragonHit;
    document.getElementById("MyHit").innerHTML = myHit;
}
```

Comment: I suppose you can just declare the variables locally in play(), unless you use it elsewhere.

Comment: this works perfect, I did the same mistake once before but couldn't figure out how I solved it back then :P will accept answer in 10min

Answer (score 1):

Create the random values in your `play()` function man. You are just creating them once, so they are obviously going to stay the same.